# Question about notation concerning differential equations - primitive functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Today I just began the study of differential equations, and I already have a question concerning the notation. This may seem trivial but I really want to understand the reason behind it.

The course I'm following presents a differential equation of the form: \begin{align*} y'(x) = f(x) \end{align*} Here $f$ is a function that only depends on $x$. We can integrate this equation as \begin{align*} y(x) = \int f(x) dx + C \end{align*} where $C$ is an integration constant and \begin{align*} F(x) = \int f(x) dx \end{align*} a primitive function of $f$. For the begin value problem with $y(x_0) = y_0$ we can then determine the integration constant and the solution is \begin{align*} y(x) = y_0 + \int_{x_0}^{x} f(t) dt = y_0 + F(x) - F(x_0). \end{align*} Now comes my question: in the integrand, why does he (my professor) change the variables to $t$? Why would he just not write $\int_{x_0}^{x} f(x) dx$ ? Is it because of the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus, which states that \begin{align*} \frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt = f(x) \end{align*} ? Some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion the explanation might be pretty simple: he didn't want to mess up the notation :) Because I do the same way, especially when I have an integral of function with additional variables and I know that some differentiation will happen after that. I know that it's a matter of taste, but I found this variant less confusing.

Comment: I agree, if you actually do the calculation $\int_0^x f(x) dx$ by hand you might end up in a confusing situation and you have to ask yourself "Is this $x$ the integration limit or the variable of integration?" if you are not careful.